# How to Determine the Default Record Type for System Mode?

Tags: administration, record-type

I have an Apex class which imports leads which runs in System mode. How do I know what recordTypeId the inserted lead will default to when there is no running User and Profile? I created a test to determine this but I'm wondering if there is a declarative setting somewhere.

Comment: I believe it still takes the default record type based on the user even though it ignores permissions and runs in System mode. What have your tests shown?

Comment: it's using the default recordType for System Administrator, which is me, but the same default recordType is assigned to Standard User so not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System Mode does't mean there is not a user or profile. "System Mode" simply means that sharing rules are ignored for SOQL/DML/SOSL/etc. If it's one of the "special" users (e.g. Automated Process User), it'll default to the Master Record Type (null record type). For all other cases, such as Web-to-Lead, a user will be assigned (usually configurable), in which case the record type will be the default for that user.

Comment: If I'm using an Apex trigger to create and insert Leads when I import a custom object, will it default to Master Record Type if there is no running user?

Comment: @Cleverlemming - there is always a Running User

Comment: Thank you. I should have been clearer. If there was no running user specified.

Comment: @Cleverlemming A trigger **always** runs in the context of a running user. There is no way to run anything in Salesforce without a security context, which requires a user.

Comment: I forget this sometimes. Is clear using System.debug('runnng user: ' + UserInfo.getUserId()); Thank you